# Force a provider with new Google Fused Location

Tags: android, gps, location

In my app, the user pick a button to retrieve his location.
If it is the first time he use the app in this store, the app will use the user location to set the store location, so it must be very accurate.
Then, when user come back to the store, he will be able to know the distance between the shop and his own location.

In this scenario, I need the shop location to be as accurate as posible => Disable Wifi Provider.
Then, when shop location is filled, I can use wifi to get user location, so that I save battery.

Right now, when wifi or 3g is enabled, getting location is very quick, but I have 250m difference from the point it should be.
I can't afford so much difference to locate a shop. So I need to force the user to use GPS provider and not wifi.

How can I do it?
AFAIK, I can only change the priority :

```
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER
LocationRequest.PRIORITY_NO_POWER
```

How Can I force the provider to be GPS???

here are my settings :

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

    /*
     * Set the update interval
     */
    mLocationRequest
            .setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    // Use high accuracy
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
    mLocationRequest
            .setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
```

Comment: Not so well. I posted another question that helps me understand more how geolocalization is managed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198377/can-anyone-explain-me-how-gps-tracking-is-working-in-android   but I feel that there is a lack of documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I half resolved my problem.

I could not restrict the provider, but I could work on accuracy.

So, While (accuracy > 100 ), keep looking for the coords.

What do you think about that?

Comment: I am experiencing the same sorts of issue. I am updating accuracy until it is under 20m, but unfortunately, the location is wrong. Have you had any success improving this?